# Geometrical interpretation of derivative of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we give any geometrical interpretation of derivative of a complex function?

Comment: It can be interpreted as an "amplitwist"; see Chapter 4 in Needham's book *Visual Complex Analysis*.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $f'(z_0) = \lambda e^{i\theta}$. Then, $f'(z_0)$ is just a rotation of angle $2\pi\theta$ composed with a homothety of ration $\lambda$, which corresponds indeed to an "amplitwist" (in the sens of the comment of Hans Lundmark).